# Django - ImproperlyConfigured: Module "django.contrib.auth.middleware"

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I'm running a virtualenv to try to learn Django, but for whatever reason after installing Django and when I try to access the default Django start page, I get the following error in the browser:

> A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.

In the terminal window where I am running the server says the following error:

> ImproperlyConfigured: Module "django.contrib.auth.middleware" does not define a "SessionAuthenticationMiddleware" attribute/class

If anyone has any insight as to why I'm getting this error in the virtualenv, I'd appreciate it. I can get the server to run correctly in a non-virtualenv setup, though.

Here is the full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Users/jruecke/Python/JSON/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/Users/jruecke/Python/JSON/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 45, in load_middleware
    mw_class = import_by_path(middleware_path)
  File "/Users/jruecke/Python/JSON/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 31, in import_by_path
    error_prefix, module_path, class_name))
ImproperlyConfigured: Module "django.contrib.auth.middleware" does not define a "SessionAuthenticationMiddleware" attribute/class
[16/Sep/2014 22:44:30] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Users/jruecke/Python/JSON/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/Users/jruecke/Python/JSON/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 45, in load_middleware
    mw_class = import_by_path(middleware_path)
  File "/Users/jruecke/Python/JSON/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 31, in import_by_path
    error_prefix, module_path, class_name))
ImproperlyConfigured: Module "django.contrib.auth.middleware" does not define a "SessionAuthenticationMiddleware" attribute/class
```

Comment: The error message says it is expecting an entry for `SessionAuthenticationMiddleware` in the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` settings. DId you try adding it ?

Comment: Since I did the exact same thing without using virtualenv, I didn't know I would need to add anything. I never got this error before. What entry would I make?

Comment: Looking at the paths in error, it points to django 1.6.5. SessionAuthenticationMiddleware is new in django 1.7

Comment: Deprecated since 1.10 - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**easy solution**

just remove

```
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
```

from

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
...
...
)
```

in your project's **settings.py**

then, it should work!

Comment: This doesn't address the underlying problem which is that the virtualenv is not set up correctly.

Comment: `sessionauthenticationmiddleware` is there for some reason. This can cause lot of other problems.

Comment: From the Django 2.0 docs, ["The SessionAuthenticationMiddleware class is removed. It provided no functionality since session authentication is unconditionally enabled in Django 1.10."](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/)

Comment: removing anything can;t fix the anything.

Answer (score 18):

I was getting the same error. But i had forgotten to get into my VirtualEnv BEFORE running my server.
So make sure that from terminal you first activate virtualenv: `source env/bin/activate`  Then run: `python manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 14):

As we can see in [Django 1.8 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.8/#deprecated-features-1-8)

> [django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware was
>   added in Django 1.7.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.8/#deprecated-features-1-8)

And you are using `Django-1.6.5` in your virtual environment, hence the `does not define` error.

Probably you have a newer version of Django installed in your "normal" environment and the server runs correctly. To fix this upgrade Django version inside your virtual environment (prior to updating Django be sure to activate your virtual environment!)

Now to add my two cents to the answers, because everything until now was repetition from [ZZY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1976791/zzy) and [user1776955](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1776955/user1776955)

If you run `pip install -U Django` you will probably bump your version to something higher than 1.10 and then the following will apply:

> In Django 1.10, session verification will be enabled regardless of
>   whether or not SessionAuthenticationMiddleware is enabled (at which
>   point SessionAuthenticationMiddleware will have no significance)

Hence it will be safe to delete it and if you update past 2.0 you will HAVE to delete it because [Django 2.0 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#django-2-0-release-notes) state that:

> [The SessionAuthenticationMiddleware class is removed. It provided no 
>   functionality since session authentication is unconditionally enabled in 
>   Django 1.10.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#miscellaneous)

Also a bit unrelated but relevant when updating to this version is that

> Support for old-style middleware using settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES is removed

As far as my experience goes it is enough to change `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` to just `MIDDLEWARE` and delete `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware'` from the list.

Answer (score 5):

Refer to the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware), the Django in your active virtualenv must be Django 1.7. And:

> This middleware must appear after django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES

Does it solve your issue?

Comment: If that was the case, no one would be able to run previous versions of Django (I actually am running 1.5 right now and it works fine).

Comment: The doc says "New in Django 1.7". You mean you're running 1.5, and there is "SessionAuthenticationMiddleware" in your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES? That's quite surprising

Comment: Your answer is correct, but you did not point to the documentation which makes the question clear (instead your link goes to the src code). Here is the claryfying link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/middleware/

Answer (score 4):

run

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

instead of

```
python manage.py runserver
```

or

```
./manage.py runserver
```

---

You can also edit the first line of manage.py replacing

```
\#!/usr/bin/env python
```

by

```
\#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

and then run ./manage.py runserver

(it seem to work, I don't know if it's authorized by django's project)

Comment: good - I had "python" in my "manage.py" and changed it to "python3", then ran "./manage.py" and it works.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a Django project with Django 1.7 and tried to run it with Django 1.6.8. And I got the same error. I have just removed

> 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',

from

> MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES =

in my project's settings.py.
And it works.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered an issue similar to this today (Using OS X Mavericks).

First of all, do you have django installed to your base OS? Before using Virtualenv I was running Django directly on the OS. The main thing I noticed is I usually type django-admin, not django-admin.py. This was calling Django outside of the virtualenv, which was version 1.7.1.

Outside of my virtualenv I ran **pip uninstall django**, then went back into my Virtualenv. Running django-admin --version without a .py at the end returned *"zsh: command not found: django-admin"* (it used to return 1.7.1), however, running django-admin.py --version returned 1.6.5.

Check to make sure you aren't accidentally bringing in an outside version of django directly from your OS, you may need to type django-admin.py

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using a version of django prior to version 1.7 (1.6.4 to be specific), and SessionAuthenticationMiddleware was not introduced until django 1.7. Hence the error

Documentation can be found here
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware

On the bottom right, you can choose the version of django. Select the appropriate version, and follow the tutorial specific to the version of django you are using.

Answer (score 1):

So, I just ran a fresh install of my virtualenv and started the server, and now it's working as expected. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are running $ source bin/activate from the root of your project. Otherwise just go ahead and wipe out your project and make a new one. And if you want to be a django dev get ready to make lots of virtualenv's.

When working on separate branches for example, it's sometimes easier to have two different virtualenv's, etc and when you move to the server you'll probably be running from a virtualenv as well. So it's a good idea to get good at making them and going through the steps.

It's easy to copy files between directories with the $ cp command.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Windows7/64 version, had the same error. Agreed with user1776955, who pointed out the version problem of Django. 
so the easiest way to do is pointing to the Django-admin.py in shell. In my case, it is:
python env\scripts\django-admin.py startproject my_django15_project

Answer (score 0):

Just run it in Python 3 instead:

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

If that would work, consider also applying some app migrations via: `python3 manage.py migrate`.

Answer (score -1):

1. I have the same error:

   ```
   File "C:\Users\DANI3\Envs\recetario\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 23, in import_string
     return getattr(module, class_name)
   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'recetario.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module: 'Module "social_django.middleware" does not define a "SocialAythExceptionMiddleware" attribute/class'
   ```
2. I corrected the error make this change:

   ```
   'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
   ```